# Delay wildcard expansion in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a wrapper on `ls` that will output the most recently modified file matching an optional pattern.

For example, `lst *pdf` should output the most recently modified file ending in `pdf`.

The following code works, but only if I enclose my argument in quotes. (I have to type `lst "*pdf"`).

```
#!/bin/bash
param="$1"
ls -1tr $param | tail -1
```

If I don't use the quotes, I get just the first file matching the pattern in alphabetical order. The reason must be that that's the first item returned when `*pdf` is interpolated by the shell, so it passes the expansion of `*pdf` to my script, instead of `"*pdf"`.

So what should I do? I suspect that I have to rewrite the script using whichever primitive functions `ls` itself draws on.

Comment: what is the `1` in `ls -1tr`?

Comment: @Allan it prints the results in one column. I guess it's not necessary if I'm piping to `tail`.

Comment: OK got you! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I  have prepared for you the following script:

```
$ cat ls2.sh 
#!/bin/bash
param="$@"
for f in "${param:=*}"
do
   stat -c '%Y %n' $f
done | sort -k1 -n | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

on the current folder:

```
$ ls -1tr
ls2.sh
2.pdf
1.pdf
3.pdf
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

output:

```
$ ./ls2.sh 
3.txt
$ ./ls2.sh *.pdf
3.pdf
$ ./ls2.sh 3.txt
3.txt
$ ./ls2.sh *
3.txt
```

Explanations:

I use `stat -c '%Y %n' $f` to display the modification time and the file name of the files, with `param="$@"` I get all the arguments passed to the script if empty I replace it by `*` to have the same behavior as ls command

Comment: I'm trying to make one little improvement here. Some of the directories have files that I didn't name myself, so they have spaces, and they get mistaken for file separators when assigning values to `f`. Reassigning `IFS` at the start treats the whole argument as one long file name. Ideas?

Comment: we might have to change our way of working and use the find command with inodes if we can not use the filenames directly...

Comment: it's interesting how it all works well if I execute everything from the command line: `IFS="|"; for f in *pdf; do stat -c "%Y %n" $f; done | sort -k1 -n | cut -d' ' -f2 | tail -1`

Comment: I'm not new to SE. Your answer didn't solve my problem. Thanks for your efforts, though.